# Moisture diffusion in air

Tags: air, diffusion, humidity

Moist air is less dense than dry air. Additionally hot air is less dense than cold air. If we have moist hot air packets above dry cold air packets. How can the mixture of these air layers be predicted by diffusion? Is the mixing influenced by other mechanisms than diffusion? Suppose we observe the said constellation in a laboratory setting so we exclude wind, coriolis force, etc...

Comment: Mixing by diffusion is very very slow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_blending_for_scuba_diving#Blending_helium_mixes

Comment: @Pieter Could you quantify? And are there other mechanisms at play than diffusion?

Answer (score 1):

Pressure gradient will also be a mechanism at play. You can measure the rate of diffusion using Graham's law. The rate of diffusion is inversely proportional to square root of density.

[Grahams law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_law)

Answer (score 0):

As per my reasoning,

For the mixing of the two components there must be some force which will have to drive the particles in vertical direction and that is done by diffusion and heating of the air particles from the earth's surface which makes them rise while passing through the layer of cold air. And while they do so, the vapor of water carried by the hot air may get liquefied and even solidified which would result in a mixture. But all the other factors which you said have a horizontal effect so they might not be as effective as the factors which I had mentioned.

The mixture formed by diffusion must be largely due to the diffusion of water in it since it has highest rate of diffusion among the other major constituents of air since it has the lowest molar mass.

Comment: What Jamieking said is there in my answer. See last portion.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the rate of diffusion of water related to its lower molar mass. The first paragraph I find a bit confusing because I mentioned to assume a laboratory setting where there is no heating from the earth, because there is no heat source.